# Perguntar ao usuário se ele realmente deseja sair

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(atividade);
        builder.setTitle("Deseja realmente sair?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                finish();
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(this, "sair",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

No trecho:
Gostaria de perguntar se realmente gostaria de sair.

Caso ele diga que sim a aplicação é finalizada .
 E caso ele diga não a tela é mantida.

Como faz já tentei funcionar, mas não quer!

Comment: Não teria que ter dois botões para ele escolher, e você tratar a resposta do usuário?

Comment: Sim...mas fiz com um não funcionou então não vai funcionar com 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
  if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(atividade);
        builder.setTitle("Deseja realmente sair?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                //finish();
               // Estamos dentro do Contexto do botão, 
              // então Usamos o nome da classse + this + método que queremos
              NomeDaActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(this, "sair",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //  finish(); -> aqui ele está fechando sempre
     builder.show(); // exibe a dialog 
    }
```

Comment: Faltou eu exibir mesmo...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode reescrever o metodo onBackPressed e mostar um toast avisando se o usuario clicar duas vezes em voltar o APP ira fechar. Para isso adicione este código ao final de sua activiry
}
    private long backPressedTime = 0;    // usado por onBackPressed
onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {        // para previnir saídas inesperadas irritantes
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (t - backPressedTime > 2000) {    // 2 segundos para sair
        backPressedTime = t;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Seu texto aqui",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {    // se pressionado novamente encerrar app
        // clean up
        super.onBackPressed();       // bye
    }

}
```

Para adicionar um texto específico na mensagem que esteja no string use Toast.makeText(this.R.string. meuTexto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)show();